# In Java with SonarQube, how to fix `Only the sign of the result should be examined`

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following line of code (where "next" is a BigDecimal):

```
if (next.compareTo(maximum) == 1) {
    maximum = next;
}
```

On the equality comparison, SonarQube gives me this warning:

> Only the sign of the result should be examined.sonarqube-inject

What does it actually mean and how can I fix that ?

Comment: `compareTo`s specification does not say that it returns `1`. It says "a value greater than 0, or less than 0 or 0". So checking strictly for `1` can lead to serious bugs, as the implementation might return `563235` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only test if it's greater than zero:

```
if (next.compareTo(maximum) > 0) {
                        maximum = next;
                    }
```

From the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of the compareTo Method:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar is suggesting to check the result of compareTo against 0, not if it returns 
directly 1, -1.

```
if (next.compareTo(maximum) >0) {
                        maximum = next;
                    }
```

You can find the reason for this suggestion in the [compareTo() Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))

Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.